# Problem with push notification with firebase on Android and IOS?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, push-notification

I want to send notifications to users on both Android and Ios operating systems through my server. And I use curl to send the message, it looks like this:

```
$fields = array(
        'condition' => $cond,
        'priority' => 'high',
        'content_available' => true,
        'notification' => $message['data'],
        'data' => $message
    );
```

If I remove **notification** field completely from my server request. Send only **data** field and handle it in  onMessageReceived() , 
then I get the notification data on Android OS very well, but the notice on IOS operating system is not received. 
But if I add **notification** field completely from my server request. 
The IOS operating system received a good notification and then the Android operating system still receives the notification but does not receive the data in  onMessageReceived()

I want a way for both operating systems to receive notifications and data

Answer (score 0):

You have to send notification and data both. Otherwise, it will not work. I do not know how to do it php but i have done it via api(postman)..
this is example

```
  {
     "to" : "f77ydJXI- ps:APA91bFoueDSpV0ya8CngPxOFGG4nHjTGoYMv7Bl2pbu1f1",
   "notification" : {
    "click_action" : "Notification_activity", 
    "body" : "new Symulti update !", 
    "title" : "new Symulti update !", 
    "icon" : "ic_notification" },
    "data" : {
      "body" : "First Notification backgraound",
      "title": "Collapsing A Backgraound",
      "key_1" : "Okay this is test",
      "key_2" : "4:24 pm 5/20/18"
}
}
```

You can find full example in this

https://gist.github.com/Muhaiminur/f0d05f53fb2b0f5a6f3419c6514f0ca5